# folder writen issue come on website after updating setup of magento 2

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, setup-di-compile, error-log

Its come many time after **upgrading** setup

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/home/soft/public_html//var/cache/" is not writable in /home/soft/public_html//vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:
```

I have already used `setup:static-content`, `setup:di-compile`, only **error log** show on website.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Set proper permission to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please set full permission for var and pub folders